# macro each raise "Segmentation fault" when iterate int array

Tags: c, macros

here is my code, I try to iterate int array and puts them, how to make it work?

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define each(item, array) \
    for (int keep = 1, count = 0, size = sizeof(array) / sizeof *(array); keep && count != size; keep = !keep, count++) \
        for (item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int is[] = {1, 2};
    each(int i, is) {
            puts(i);
        }
    return (0);
};
```

Comment: run `gcc -E` and see the output of that macro if you want to debug it.  Also, OMG, don't do that in a macro .. it is impossible to debug (as you are learning now).

Comment: What do you think about this `item=array+count`?

Comment: Use range-based for loops in C++11

Answer (score 1):

Macro is OK

Call and body of `each()` loop are faulty.

Notice `item = (array) + count` is adding `count` to a pointer (`array` converts to `&array[0]`) and the result of that should be a pointer.  So `int i` should be `int *i`.

`puts(const char *s)` expects a string, not an `int`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int is[] = {1, 2};
    // each(int i, is) {
    each(int *i, is) {
      // puts(i);
      printf("%d\n", *i);
      }
    return (0);
};
```

Output

```
1
2
```

Comment: Can i may macro "each" more simple, I mean use "each" with "i" not "*i"

Comment: You could use `item = *((array) + count)` in your macro.

Comment: @The Dark True about macro change idea.